# Different forms of Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-transform

Why is that some text books use $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)$? And some use  $\left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)$?

Comment: That's not important, actually. It's a matter of fashion to say. If one is using angular frequency $\omega$ as other domain variable, then in the forward and backward equation, a coefficient of $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ appears. You can distribute it as $\left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \right)^\alpha \left( \frac{1}{2\pi} \right)^{1-\alpha}$ where $\alpha $ arbitrary in forward and backward relations, respectively. Also you can use $f$ in $\omega=2\pi f$ as the other domain variable and get rid of $2 \pi$ for the good. Some authors (e.g. engineering math) prefer symmetry and use $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}$ in both.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a physicist, you would (generally) like to use
$$
\hat f (\xi)=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\hbar}{2\pi}\right)^d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)e^{-i \hbar \, x \cdot \xi}\,dx
$$
the advantage is that it takes into account planck's constant, i.e it is unitary, $\lVert f\rVert_2 = \lVert \hat f\rVert_2^2$, and shares the same constant as its inverse, but $\widehat{f * g} = \sqrt{\frac{(2\pi)^d}{\hbar^d}}\hat{f}\hat{g} \not=\hat{f}\hat{g}$. (Generally) Mathmaticians use
$$
\hat f (\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)e^{-2\pi i\, x \cdot \xi}\,dx,\qquad \mathcal{F}^{-1}f(x) =\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)e^{2\pi i\, x \cdot \xi}\,d\xi
$$
this is a $*$-algebra morphism from $L^1(G=\mathbb{R}^d)$ to $C_0(G)$, $\widehat{f * g} =\hat{f}\hat{g}$. and it is unitary at the level of $L^2(G)$ it has all the right properties and one does not have to bother with any constant.

On the other hand some people, for reasons unclear, prefer to use
$$
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^d} \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)e^{-i \,x \cdot \xi}\,dx
$$
this one doesnt have any good property and its inverse doesnt even have the same constant, i.e.
$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}f(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x)e^{i\,x \cdot \xi}\,d\xi.
$$

But as you might notice, all are basically the same transform minus some change of variable of the form $x \mapsto cx$, they all share the same properties but you have to keep track of the constants.